# What does this line of code mean (Bitwise Operator)

Tags: c, pointers, bitwise-operators

```
#define LODWORD(x) (*((unsigned int*)&(x)))
```

I'm translating C code to python and can't quite get this. If anyone can explain how to read this or what it means it'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are no bitwise operators here. The `&` symbol is the address-of operator.

Comment: This code is actually Undefined Behaviour, but the intent probably was to select the least significant 32 bits of a 64-bit integer

Comment: It is not bitwise operator as it does not operate on the bits level - and `&` has a complete different meaning here;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a macro for getting the lower `DWORD` ( 32bits ) of a 64 bit variable, there's most likely an associated `HIDWORD` macro as well to get the higher 32 bits. Other comments have pointed out some flaws with the macro, but it's a fairly common idiom for accomplishing this.

Some equivalent Python code might be:

```
def LODWORD(x):
    return x & 0xFFFFFFFF
```

Comment: There is so this code is basically splitting the 64 bit int it's dealing with into the first half of the 64 bits and the second half if the 64 bits

Comment: That's correct. More specifically, this is getting the 'lower' 32 bits. I've updated the answer to give a simple implementation in Python.

Comment: the hiword one uses x+1 do I just use that in place of x here.

Comment: Try this:
    `def HIWORD(x):
         return (x & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000) >> 32`

Comment: one more question for you. This code uses an unsigned long long int. Is that necessary in python. Or do their ints automatically adjust.

Comment: *it's a fairly common idiom*  Ugh. Anyone writing that doesn't understand C.  Depending on what's passed to the macro, it's either useless, or undefined behavior and a strict aliasing violation, and if it doesn't blow up it will return the wrong results on a big-endian system.

Comment: I certainly didn't say it's correct, but google it and you'll see it's used all over the place!

Comment: @ajxs: There is only one integer type in Python from user's perspective, `int`, which autopromotes transparently to biginteger (i.e. size limited by available memory). (You can get int64 from C if you use `numpy` library.)

Comment: @Amadan i.e. there is now *one* integer type in Python 3 which is *always* big integer consuming as much memory as is needed to exactly store its value

Comment: This macro is /not/ getting the lower DWORD ( 32bits ) of a 64 bit variable. It merely gets the `unsigned int` at the same starting address as the specified variable. The return value heavily depends on the implementation: for example `int8_t foo; int32_t bar = LODWORD(foo);` reads beyond the memory occupied by `foo`. Also on some macines `int` has only 16 bytes.

Comment: @N.Paul You're totally correct. The original asker was asking for hints as to the intent of the macro, and I think judging by the name and the code that we can discern this is what it *intends* to do. I certainly wouldn't encourage it's use, but based on the context of the question that doesn't matter.

Comment: @user3851290, if this answer helped you can you please select it as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 3):

```
&(x)                  // get address of `x` as a pointer to whatever x is
(unsigned int*)(...)  // cast it to a pointer to `unsigned int`
*(...)                // then read that address' contents as if it was `unsigned int`
```

I'd use `union` if really needed, and only if I knew the CPU architecture, otherwise this is very very unsafe :P

Comment: could you tell me the python equivalent?

Comment: Well, no, because Python does not have pointers, for one thing. We'd need a bit of a wider context (for instance, exactly what `x` is - a struct, an int32, an int64, a float...? All of those would be dealt with differently in Python.)

Comment: in this context it is an int64

Comment: lol to make it worse it's unsigned, I'm dealing with some kind of encryption code

Comment: Then probably `x & (2 ** 32 - 1)`, if on little-endian processor. (EDIT: @ajxs' `0xFFFFFFFF` is equivalent to this.)

Comment: It won't really matter to you whether it's signed or unsigned, this code just operates on the bit level, the context of said bits is up to the application.

Answer (score 0):

First by using `#define` defines a macro that does substitution. It is a macro with an argument, a so-called "function-like macro".
After the `#define` when an expression `LODWORD(whatever you write here)` occurs it will be replaced by `(*((unsigned int*)&(whatever you write here)))` before the code is fed into the compiler. This is called "macro expansion". The compiler will only see expanded expressions.

The macro expanded expression of `LODWORD(foo)` does the following:

`(foo)` is common idiom in macros: Put arguments into parentheses to avoid operator precedence errors.

`&(foo)` means "the address of `(foo)`" (a "pointer"). This creates a value that represents the memory location of `foo`. It is of type "pointer to the type of `foo`" .

`(unsigned int*)&(foo)` converts "the adress of `foo`" into "the address of the `unsigned int` `foo`". The operator `(insigned int*)` is called a "cast operator". It changes the result type "pointer to the type of `foo`" into "pointer to an `unsigned int`".

`((unsigned int*)&(foo))` overrides operator precedence. Now you have "pointer to an `unsigned int` at the memory location of `foo`.

`*((unsigned int*)&(foo))` returns the value of the  `unsigned int` at the memory location of `foo` (even if `foo` is not an unsigned integer and even if that memory location violates alignment requirements for an `unsigned int`).

`(*((unsigned int*)&(foo)))` is yet another common idiom in macros: Put the entire expression into parentheses to avoid operator precedence errors. Then the macro can always be used as if it was a function.

Comment: If `foo` is not an `int` or `unsigned int` then the code is *undefined behaviour*

Comment: it is an unsigned int

Comment: And if `foo` is an `int` or `unsigned int`, the result is simply a cast to `unsigned` of little use, otherwise it is a *type-punned* `X` in violation of the *strict-aliasing rule*.